# Procedural Texture Repetition boundaries Problem

Tags: texturing, materials, procedural

I'm trying to build a texture mapping that can do the following things:

- Adjust number of repetitions, Right, Left Top and Bottom
- Space the tiles apart from each other
- Scale Rotate Translate Entire picture with tiles.
- Scale Rotate Translate Tiles within repeats.

Now, in this example I almost succeeded, but I'm having a problem, because if the texture is close to the border edges of the tile (left and bottom) the texture stretches across the entire object. However, this does not happen if the texture is located on the top or right side.

Everything works fine until the texture touches the left and bottom boundaries

I'm not sure why and how I can possibly correct this.

Any idea?

[image]